# How to inherit the SKspritenode and create by self.childNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a problem dealing with inheritance for the skspritenode
I have created a skspritenode in the scence and want to inherit the sksprite to a car class

**Car Class**

```
class Car : SKSpriteNode {
  var CurrentLocation = 1
}
```

**GameScene**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var leftCar = Car()

    func setUp() {
       leftCar = self.childNode(withName: "leftCar") as! SKSpriteNode
    }
}
```

I dont know what the meaning of Cannot assign value of type 'SKSpriteNode' to Car and how to reslove this error, thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leftCar` is of type `Car` so compiler is complaining to cast `childNode` as `Car` instead of `SKSpriteNode` shown below.

```
func setUp() {
   if let car = self.childNode(withName: "leftCar") as? Car {
      leftCar = car
   }
}
```

BTW, you already initialized `leftCar` in the same `GameScene` so you can simply use that instead of assigning it again.

---

Set custom class `Car` in `GameScene.sks` for `leftCar` node as shown in below image,

[image]

Comment: the program started while the controller method for car cant work. my suspicion is I create the Skspritenode inside the gamescence.sks which it is not treated as Car class therefore it cant works. What should i do for this case? (I am new to IOS programming  )

Comment: should i manually create the car inside the gamescence.swift so that I can create the leftcar as the object for Car?

Comment: @ChakWingMak Please see the attached image and set custom class in sks file.

Comment: Really thanks! you have helped me to solve the problem